# MySql .Net Connection:

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am running into an odd issue using the MySql .Net connector (v. 6.6.5).  The error being generated indicates that a column that isn't in the table definition is not present in the field list, and some random garbled character which was *not* in the sql query will be present.  Some Examples:

```
Unknown column 'VoŬume' in 'field list'

Unknown column 'TradeEate' in 'field list'
```

There are many tables with the same basic definition, just different table names.  Upon running a describe, this is what I always receive from the table that has generated the error:

[image]

This error occurs sporadically, and if I run the query again the error will not replicate.  Any insight on how this is occuring would be appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT (INCLUDE SAMPLE QUERY)

```
    BEGIN; SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0; 
    SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0; SET NAMES 'utf8'; 
    INSERT INTO `eod_ETF_ETXIUSAQJK` (`TradeDate`, `Open`, `High`, `Low`, `Close`, `Volume`, `AdjustedClose`) 
    VALUES ('2011-07-08 00:00:00', '100', '102.5', '30.0266', '66.2047', '9275592', '66.2047') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Open` = '100', `High` = '102.5', `Low` = '30.0266', `Close` = '66.2047', `Volume` = '9275592', `AdjustedClose` = '66.2047'; 
   SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 1; 
   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; 
   COMMIT;
```

Comment: Did you wrote the query in your code? Or are you auto generating query from some source. the problem seems in Query you are sending to MySql, try to print the query on browser before it gets executed to see if it has wired characters if so then check your source of Query.

Comment: show me your `query` as well plz.

Comment: check my answer again plz.

Comment: @SumitGupta sample query that is being sent added.  (data values are mocked, format is the same).  Query is generated in code.

Comment: `INSERT INTO `eod_ETF_ETXIUSAQJK` (`TradeDate`, `Open`, `High`, `Low`, `Close`, `Volume`, `AdjustedClose`) 
    VALUES ('2011-07-08 00:00:00', '100', '102.5', '30.0266', '66.2047', '9275592', '66.2047') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Open` = '100', `High` = '102.5', `Low` = '30.0266', `Close` = '66.2047', `Volume` = '9275592', `AdjustedClose` = '66.2047';` , ichecked your query and it works fine,,i think you need to check your code again, check in another query as well if you are using

Comment: @Rahul  As a debugging step, I have tried writing the query to a file every time before it sends to the database.  In every case where this happens, the query in the file is correct.  The error is happening somewhere farther down the line.  Somehow the query is getting garbled after going to the MySql dll.

Answer (score 0):

It looks likes to be a `Query Problem`, I think you are selecting wrong field. You should `select` `Volume` not `VoŬume` and `TradeDate` not `TradeEate` in your query.

**Reason For Error**

> I suspect that error may comes from a different query where you did not
>   surround the code with single quotes. It may be the reason.Please
>   check.

Hope it works.

Comment: The query does use the correct field names generated in code.  I will edit my question to show an example query to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  After running the same code on several other servers with no issues, I isolated the problem to a particular server.  The issue was faulty RAM.  http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm for the win.